# how to update inner objects of an entity in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Am relatively new to springboot and I have a scenario.I have users and I have jobs. A user can apply to many jobs and a job can be applied by multiple user.I have job and user entities with bidirectional relationship as follows

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "job_applications")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Collection<JobApplicant> applicants= new ArrayList<>();

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "applicants",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     @JsonManagedReference
    private Collection<Job> jobs= new ArrayList();
```

The challenge I want to associate a user with a job programatically and this is what I was trying in my service class

```
public void addJobToUserJobList(int useId,int jobId) {
        Job job=jobRepository.getOne(jobId);
        System.out.println("Job found: "+job.getName());
        JobApplicant applicant= applicantRepo.getOne(useId);
        Set<Job>jobslist= new HashSet();
        jobslist.add(job);
        applicant.setJobs(jobslist);
        applicantRepo.save(applicant);
        jobRepository.save(job);
    }
```

When I hit **applicants/1/25** end-point this code in the controller the join table is not updated.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/applicants/{userid}/{jobId}", method = { RequestMethod.PUT, 
RequestMethod.GET })
public void applyToJob(@PathVariable int userid,@PathVariable int jobId) {
        jobService.addJobToUserJobList(userid, jobId);
}
```

Is there a better approach to doing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was the owning side of my relatioship. I  was saving updating my jobApplicant entity which was not the owning side hence it could not update the join table. I made the entity the owning side and it worked as below

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "jobs",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "job_applications")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Collection<JobApplicant> applicants= new ArrayList<>();

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     @JsonManagedReference
    private Collection<Job> jobs= new ArrayList();
```